# I want to capture the last day's (today) posts in a category in the numbered order in acf

Tags: wp-query

I want to capture the last day's (today) posts in a category in the numbered order in acf. I am using the code below. can sort by category. but it doesn't just bring up today's posts but all posts. what am I doing wrong?

```php
    <?php 
   $today = date('Ymd');
           $args = array(
            'cat'  => array(4,),
            'date'  => 'today',
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status'  => 'publish',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'asc',
            'meta_key' => 'sira',
            'paged'             => $paged,

          );

            $query = new WP_Query($args);

            while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        ?>
```

Comment: Some notes, why is `Today` capitalised, `'30'` wrapped in quotes, and what's the raw format of the `acf_sira` meta value? Also `post__not_in` is _extremely_ slow and expensive

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'm not very good at writing code. the code is like this right now. acf value 'sira'
but unfortunately it pulls all content instead of today's content.

<?php 
   $today = date('Ymd');
           $args = array(
            'cat'  => array(4,),
   'date'  => 'today',
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'post_status'  => 'publish',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
   'order' => 'asc',
   'meta_key' => 'sira',
    );

            $query = new WP_Query($args);

            while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        ?>

Comment: please update your question using the edit link to add new code, you can't put blocks of code in comments, it breaks it and puts it all on one line. Note that these are just comments where people can ask clarifying questions, nobody has written a solution/answer yet